# Where to start Android drivers with I2C

Tags: android, linux, driver, i2c

Thanks for taking a moment to read my question. I am a starving intern and I really want to get some work done!

I have a sensor device, OEM, that I will be adding to a dragonboard like this. http://mydragonboard.org/

Unfortunately I have wasted a lot of time researching how to write a driver to interact with my sensor over I2C and I have ended up confused, mostly because none of my resources are consistent with where to put what code. I read a lot of "Embedded Android", "Linux Device Drivers", and "Sensor PortingGuide" (Oreilly, Oreilly, TI) and have not gotten a solid answer on how to GET IT DONE.

My goal is to eventually have this implemented with a HAL and available to the SensorService and Sensor Manager.

Thanks
!

Comment: Andros: SO is good place for very specific question, but general or vague questions are rarely answered. I would recommend to write down what is your problem exactly.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some source code.

Comment: @Andros Have you installed the source tree?  Try looking at some of the other Android kernel mode drivers.

Comment: I need to know how drivers get written for Android using linux i2c subsystem. I realize this is probably the wrong forum to get help for general lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

i2c driver does not change much depending on Android or Linux.
You can go through a simple already implemented i2c driver in http://lxr.linux.no/

one example : understand implemented driver at lxr:
/kernel/drivers/input/misc/*